# Running Codeigniter on Portable XAMPP

Tags: codeigniter, xampp

I just downloaded XAMPP Portable from this site, and installed it on my USB flash drive.

```
https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/5.6.20/
```

When im running my web it shows error like this:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Only variable references should be returned by reference

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 257
```

But when im running it with normal XAMPP (that is installed on my hard drive) it's running fine. Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change on eline in your system/core/Common.php

from

```
return $_config[0] =& $config;
```

to

```
$_config[0] =& $config;
return $_config[0];
```